# Spaces in Xcode project names, what's the best practice?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm creating a new Xcode project and the name will have a space on it, like "Foo Bar". I am inclined to name it "Foo Bar" because that's the actual name of the app as it appears on the top menu, the file system ("Foo Bar.app"), command-tab, etc. But then, I end up with odd looking folders and targets, like "Foo BarTest".

What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 7):

I use one word camelCase names like "FooBar" for developing: file names, paths, etc. To me, it makes sense to make my life a little easier when the occasional shell script needs to be written or something, as there's no need to worry about internal spaces. For sure, the 'make' utility chokes horribly on spaces…

But really, it's because I don't see the downside: the name of my FooBar.app is going to be localized *anyhow*, in English as well as whatever other languages, so the app in Finder *looks* like "Foo Bar", and in the About Menu, etc.

So it's FooBar to me in all my coding, and Foo Bar everywhere to the user.

---

How to localize the name of your app:

Start with a newly created Xcode Cocoa application, named "FooBar". Initially, everything is "FooBar", everywhere: the Xcode variables ${PRODUCT_NAME} and ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}, and the name of your built app in the Finder.

Now we want to *only* change the name as it appears in the Finder.
Properly, this is no more or less than localization.

In the app's Info.plist file, add the key "CFBundleDisplayName", and make its value identical to the value for the already existing key "CFBundleName".

The initial value of CFBundleName is "${PRODUCT_NAME}", an Xcode variable, and you can just copy & paste that. Alternatively you can "hard code" each of those keys to some literal string, but if you do that, then you must also update the "Product Name" value in the "Build Settings" pane for the application.

Then, you need to do the actual localization.

If it does not exist already (it probably does), create and add to the project an "InfoPlist.strings" localization file, id est (assuming English to be the "main" language) the file which resides in and is copied to the app's Resources folder in a sub-folder named "en.lproj".

In this file, add the same two keys that appear in the Info.plist file, in this format, giving them the value that you want your app to appear as in the Finder:

```
/* Localized versions of Info.plist keys */
CFBundleName        = "Foo & Bar";
CFBundleDisplayName = "Foo & Bar";
```

That's it!  The app is now "FooBar.app" as far as UNIX is concerned, but it appears to the user as "Foo & Bar" in the Finder.

Comment: I might be missing something here, how is it that the bundle can be called FooBar.app and appear as Foo Bar in Finder?

Comment: Just to confirm, instead of "$(PRODUCT_NAME)" in your CFBundleName, you have "Foo Bar"?

Comment: Also, if someone opens /Applications, do they see Foo Bar or FooBar.app?

Comment: I set Foo Bar as CFBundleName and CFBundleDisplayName but the file was displayed as FooBar.app, not Foo Bar.app (yes, I know the .app depends on Finder preferences, I'm just using it to make it clear what I'm talking about). What I ended up doing is having PRODUCT_NAME as Foo Bar and PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME as FooBar and made the bundle and other identifiers depend on module name instead of product name. Seems a much healthier setup than Xcode's default.

Comment: Pablo, I made a complete mess in responding to your follow up question.  Since then, I've looked at, AND TESTED, and remembered, and tested...  Part of what I said before was upside-down from what I should have said.  I put the guaranteed, tried & tested method as an edit to my response to your first question, above.  HTH.

Answer (score 4):

I stopped using spaces in my Xcode project names.

There are circumstances(*) where you have to import your module into your unit test module, so in Swift you end up writing

```
import Foo Bar
```

in your Foo BarTest module, which is something the Swift compiler doesn't like.

(*) this is at least necessary when you use core data and you want to use your core data model and classes in your unit tests.

Comment: If a project name has a space, then, in the module name, use underscores. E.g., Foo_Bar.

Answer (score 0):

The only "best practices" for naming your project is using common sense. It's probably best to match the project name to the resulting app name that it will produce or vice versa.

I prefer one word names mostly — and short, especially if it's a `CLI` related project. Obviously that's not the case here, so name it however works best for you.

Comment: The question is about the Xcode project name, not the app's name.

Comment: It's generally tantamount. Why would you name your project differently from the app that it produces?

Comment: That's exactly what the OP was asking. @zeppenwolf has an example but there are more reasons to have differing names.